# Oracle WebCenter 12C Portal Domain Configuration using Ansible

Tags: configuration, ansible, weblogic

I'm trying to configure Weblogic WebCenter 12C Portal Domain via Ansible on CentOS 7, but still can't find the way how to do it. So far I could install weblogic and weblogic portal with DB via Ansible. But I don't know how to configure Webcenter Portal. **/opt/app/middleware/oracle_common/common/bin/config.sh** Have anyone already done this step via Ansible? If yes, please share with me this info if you have. I also tried to find any related info on google, but no luck, so I post my question here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just run config.sh in silent mode:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/core/ASINS/silent_install.htm#CBHECCJB

4.8 Configuring Your Oracle Fusion Middleware Product in Silent Mode

example:

```
./config.sh -silent -response response_file
```

I'm not sure this will work for Webcenter Portal, however, the likelihood of this is great.

response_file is quite convenient to form in ansible using "templates"

Comment: Thanks for the respond Destros, yes I already have the beginning of it,  I need the further configuration steps.

Comment: Isn’t it enough to just run this script with passing the filled response_file to it?

Comment: It's enough to start it, I agree w/u, but not till the end.